# No browser.dom.window.dump.enabled in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

I'm using a firefox developer [tutorial](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/03/18/video-tutorial-extensions-bootcamp-zero-to-hello-world-in-45-minutes/) and one of the options asks to update the browser.dom.window.dump.enabled option but it doesn't seem to exist in my version of Firefox (4.0.1 in Ubuntu). The tutorial is two years old so has the option had a name change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually create the value yourself if it doesn't exist already. Also I found [a blog entry here that explains the differences in writing for Firefox 4.0 with the tutorial you mentioned](http://anthonystechblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/how-to-write-an-add-on-for-firefox-4-0/).